# Angular Js Unexpected Token error Dynamic Routes

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs

I'm getting getting several "unexpected token <" errors when I try to create a dynamic route.
Normal routes work fine. So if I set the following route:

```
.when('/user',{
    templateUrl: 'views/user/new', 
    controller: "addUserCtrl"
  })
```

The request goes to the server and gets caught by my express catch all route handler, then angular kicks in and requests express' api route, api/user, binds data, controller and template and I see a nice page. Everything works fine. No errors.

If I try to create a dynamic route or a route with more depth, I get the unexpected token error, when I try to request that route:

```
.when('/user/:id',{
    templateUrl: 'views/user/new', 
    controller: "addUserCtrl"
  })
```

For example, when I request /user/3, i get the error, and it the addUserCtrl is never called. Any ideas what could be causing this.

```
.when('/user/show,{
    templateUrl: 'views/user/new', 
    controller: "addUserCtrl"
  })
```

requesting /user/show will also throw the error. In the console the error shows up next to the request for all of angular files (angular.js, App.js, services.js, controllers.js, filters.js, directives.js) that I load in the body of my index.html.

I've noticed that this problem happens whenever I add more than one slash to the route. If I try /user/show, I can see the following requests:

```
   /user/show

   syntax errors for the below:
   /user/js/App.js
   /user/js/lib/angular/angular.js
   /user/js/filters.js
   /user/js/controllers.js'
   /user/js/services.js
   /user/js/directives.js
```

If I try /abc/def, I will get the following request:

```
   /abc/def

    syntax errors for the below:
   /abc/js/App.js
   /abc/js/lib/angular/angular.js
   /abc/js/filters.js
   /abc/js/controllers.js'
   /abc/js/services.js
   /abc/js/directives.js
```

Comment: It's possibly because /user/show and /user/:id conflict?  Try getting rid of one.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issues because I was actually replacing /user/:id with /user/show.  I remove all routes and have only one. In fact, I removed all routes and still got the syntax error unexpected toekn error, which makes it more confusing. if I try something like /abc/def it will give me the error. When ever I enter two or more slashes in the route, I get the error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and just as atentaten describes the problem was caused by relative paths to js-files. However, it has nothing to do with Express. It can just as well be caused by relative include paths from script tags in the head of a html file. So, to clarify, I changed my HTML from:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is not really an angular issue, but an express issue.

The problem was that the beginning slashes were missing from my angular js includes in my index.jade:

```
script(src='js/lib/angular/angular.js')
script(src='js/App.js')
script(src='js/services.js')
script(src='js/controllers.js')
script(src='js/filters.js')
script(src='js/directives.js')
```

I changed them to this:

```
script(src='/js/lib/angular/angular.js')
script(src='/js/App.js')
script(src='/js/services.js')
script(src='/js/controllers.js')
script(src='/js/filters.js')
script(src='/js/directives.js')
```

And the errors went away. Although the js loaded without the starting slash, it was still causing a problem with express, creating the syntax error, which probably broke angular, but I'm not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 1):

The templateUrl needs to be absolute else Express will choke if there is more than one slash/level of depth in the url:

```
.when('/user/show,{
  templateUrl: '/views/user/new', /* add slash */
  controller: "addUserCtrl"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens for ui-router dynamic route in angularJS application. I have the same error. solved by changing the path

```
<script src="app/components/services/campaign.services.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/app/components/services/campaign.services.js"></script>
```

But in my case index.html file path is generated by gulp task **gulp-inject** so i changes the config of gulp-inject like

```
inject: { addRootSlash: true }
```

and it works for me :)